# I would like to get this patent assigned to my company since it infringes on DQWA, which is assigned to Ether-2. How do I do that?

Tags: assignment

In reference to the patent: [US20140148197](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140148197)

Answer (score 1):

The linked document is an application. The issued patent is [US9702961B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9702961B2/en). If you believe it infringes on a patent your company owns, then the assignee will need to get a license in order to utilize it. Its up to your company to initiate a law suit if you think your intellectual property is being infringed. I'm not a lawyer, but my understanding is that patents are property and this one would belong to assignee: Intel Corporation. I do not believe the US government can just assign the patent to another company. So there is no way to get the patent to be assigned to your company short of purchasing it from Intel.

Comment: There is a way to sue for ownership if the idea was stolen. Doesn't seem so from the question though.